# Error handling for invalid JSON in kafka sink connector

Tags: mongodb, error-handling, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a sink connector for mongodb, that takes json from a topic and puts it into the mongoDB collection. But, when I send an invalid JSON from a producer to that topic (e.g. with an invalid special character ") => `{"id":1,"name":"\"}`, the connector stops. I tried using errors.tolerance = all, but the same thing is happening. What should happen is that the connector should skip and log that invalid JSON, and keep the connector running. My distributed-mode connector is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "sink-mongonew_test1",  
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "topics": "error7",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://****:27017", 
    "database": "abcd", 
    "collection": "abc",
    "type.name": "kafka-connect",
    "key.ignore": "true",

    "document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
    "value.projection.list": "id",
    "value.projection.type": "whitelist",
    "writemodel.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.UpdateOneTimestampsStrategy",

    "delete.on.null.values": "false",

    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",

    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "crm_data_deadletterqueue",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you producing invalid json anyway? And how? If you use any json library, it doesn't produce invalid json strings

Comment: And what version of Connect are you using?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm building up a kafka-streams application where the possibility of an invalid JSON exists. The connect is of version connect-api-1.0.1.3.0.0.0-1634.jar, and kafka is 3.0

Comment: Again, not clear how your producers are creating invalid JSON. Kafka Streams has its own error handling and you should filter out invalid records anyway... Kafka has no version 3.0. Confluent Platform 3.0 is really old, relatively speaking. HDP 3.0 uses Kafka 1.x, I think... And if you installed HDF, Cloudera would recommend that you use Nifi

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/

Comment: yes, I have. Is there any thing missing in my connector?

Comment: Have you tried researching when those features where added into Kafka Connect?

Answer (score 0):

> Since **Apache Kafka 2.0, Kafka Connect has included error handling options**, including the functionality to route messages to a dead letter queue, a common technique in building data pipelines.

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/

As commented, you're using  `connect-api-1.0.1.*.jar`, version 1.0.1, so that explains why those properties are not working

Your alternatives outside of running a newer version of Kafka Connect include Nifi or Spark Structured Streaming

Comment: Is this the only jar I should replace (with the latest version) in the libs folder inside kafka?

Comment: No. That imports JARs like kafka-clients and kafka_2.11 and zookeeper-3.4.13,  connect-utils,, etc etc...

Comment: You don't need to use Kafka Connect provided by Hortonworks. Just download the newest Kafka libraries on the same machines and configure the newer property files for Connect Distributed and run it against your existing Kafka bootstrap servers. Cloudera doesn't officially support Kafka Connect API anyway, so you're really on your own there